# Unable to to get simple Javascript working in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm reasonably experienced with PHP, MySQL, HTML and CSS, but I am struggling in the early stages of learning Javascript. I have a script which functions as expected in IE, Opera and Chrome, but not Firefox.

Here are the two relevant scripts. This is my first post here, so I apologise if I've not done it right. Nonetheless, guidance would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<!-- The purpose of this script is to to capture the details of the hotlink that was clicked without affecting the visible hotlink destination -->
<!-- This script works in IE, Chrome and Opera, but not Firefox -->

<head>
<title>Dev</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<script src="jQuery.js"></script>

<script>
function myBasic(pgnm){
        var page = pgnm ;
        var theLink = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByClassName('theLink')) ;
        // the alert window displays the correct data
        window.alert(theLink + "\n" + page);
        jQuery.post("catchIt.php?link=" + theLink + "&pg=" + page) ;
        return true ;
    }   
</script> 

</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">

<!-- This is a series of many hotlinked URLs that need to be recorded and stored in a mySql table -->
<!-- The pagename and hotlinks will be inserted via a PHP script -->

  <p><a onClick="myBasic('pagename.php');" href="destination.php" class="theLink">(Not) Working script</a></p>
  <p><a onClick="myBasic('anotherPagename.php');" href="http://example.com/destination.php?a=1&b=2" class="theLink">Another (Not) Working script</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

(catchIt.php)

```
$thisString  = $_GET['link'] ;
$page = $_GET['pg'] ;

$thisDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
$thisIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ;

// the remained of this code has already been developed to write the details to the mySql table
// the code below is there to prove the success of this script
$thisString .= '
' . $thisDate . '
' . $thisIp . ' 
' . $page ;

$file = fopen("theWords.txt","w");

fwrite($file, $thisString) ;

fclose($file) ;

 ?>
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong in Firefox? Can you explain the problem?

Comment: `var theLink = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByClassName('theLink')) ;` doesn't make a lot of sense. You're relying on implicitly converting an HTMLCollection to a string. (On Chrome, that will return the string `"%5Bobject%20HTMLCollection%5D"`.) What is the goal of that line?

Comment: With apologies, I don't believe the code in the question "...functions as expected in IE, Opera and Chrome..." You're launching asynchronous ajax in response to a link click, trying to send `"%5Bobject%20HTMLCollection%5D"` to the PHP page (but it won't get there, because the page initiating the request is torn down before the request really gets going, because it goes to the destination page.

Comment: If you're trying to post to the server the details of the link that was clicked, with the current code you're going to have a race condition between the AJAX request completing, and the browser unloading the current page.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var theLink = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByClassName('theLink')) ;
```

sets `theLink` to `"%5Bobject%20HTMLCollection%5D"` on Chrome. If the goal was to get the `href` of the link that was clicked, you need to pass the link into your function, and use its `href` property. Minimal changes to do that:

```
<a onClick="myBasic(this, 'pagename.php');" ...
```

and

```
function myBasic(element, pgnm){
    var page = pgnm ;
    var theLink = encodeURIComponent(element.href);
    // ...
```

Then, though, you'd have to send a **synchronous** ajax request (which is a really bad idea) in order to ensure the post completes before the page is torn down because of following the link.

You could prevent the default action (following the link) and then navigate to the page when the ajax finishes.

But both synchronous ajax and preventing the default will give you misleading stats, because right-clicking the link and opening it in a new tab/window won't be recorded. Or if someone copies the link address, opens a new window, and pastes it, that too won't be recorded.

Fundamentally, this approach can't work reliably. The page you land on needs to send the information that you've landed on it.

Comment: Thank you all for your prompt comments. It's not a surprise to me that I am going in almost entirely the wrong direction!  ;-)

Comment: And TJC, yep, as published here it doesn't work in the browsers as I claimed...It did work though, so I'm at a bit of a loss as to why (a caching issue of some sort perhaps). My only note is that (from what I had read) the onClick will happen and the 'return true' will then allow forwarding to the href. Thanks for the suggested modifications to the code - I will experiment. Clearly, further (deep) thought is needed here, but if I may I'll come back in a day or two.